# Groovy: remove specific characters from end of string

Tags: groovy

I have a string that might end with multiple `\n` (the two symbols, not a newline).

How can I remove that from the end of the string?

For example: `abc\ndef\n\n` should become `abc\ndef`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
s = "abc\ndef\n\n"
assert s.replaceAll(/\n*$/, "") == "abc\ndef"
```

The section between `//` looks for any amount of `\n` and the `$` represents the end of the string. So, replace any amount of newlines with nothing else after them, with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple task a simple `trim()` would suffice:

```
assert 'abc\ndef' == 'abc\ndef\n\n\n\n'.trim()
```

Comment: As I said it's the two symbols, not newline character, so rather `\\n` when you put it in a string.